# subsets and annihilators

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:Prove if $U \subset V$, then $V^{\perp} \subset U^{\perp}$.

Proof: Let $f \in V$ such that $[f,u]=0$ for all $u\in U$. That is $U^{\perp}$ consists of all linear functionals such that $U$ vanishes: f=0. The annihilator of a subset is itselft a vector space so $\emptyset^{\perp}=V$, $\forall V$ where $V^\perp = 0$. Thus, $U \subset V$,then $0 \subset V^\perp \subset U^\perp$.

Honestly, I need help with this. Please.

Comment: What are you even asking? Also, $U^{\bot}$ contains vector, not linear functionals. Please rephrase your question so we will know what you are asking.

Comment: well pretty much its Prove if $U \subset V$, then $V^ \perp \subset U^ \perp$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in V^{\perp}$. Then for all $v \in V$, we have $\langle v,x \rangle = 0$. In particular, for $u \in U \subset V$, we have $\langle u,x \rangle = 0$. Thus $x \in U^{\perp}$ and $V^{\perp} \subset U^{\perp}$.

Comment: You know anybody can just spoonfeed an answer to the OP like this, but is it any good in terms of teaching someone to think for themselves?

Comment: Sometimes people need to see how its done before they can attempt it themselves. Mayb its not how u do it but for others it Is

Comment: @RuthGutierrez If you always have to see how it is done first, how will you ever be able to discover anything new? But maybe you are right, I shouldn't generalize...I just wanted to challenge you to try and find the answer by yourself, it is much more rewarding and you will find that you gan a deeper insight into the problem, which also aids memory...

Comment: Yes your right that's true but sometimes that doesn't work for ppl. I had this teacher that followed that philosphy and would tell us to read the book and figure it out. He wud just walk around the class while we read and tried problems out bcuz he believed you learn more if you do it yourself. Of course I was like well I wasted a lot of money to learn by myself. Its kind of like well then why are you even here. But again this thought works for some things and other things it doesn't, but I do appreciate what you said

Answer (score 0):

A specific vector $u$ annihilates a polynomial $p(X)$ if $p(u)=0_K$ for some $K-$algebra (vector space with added structure in terms of some binary operation on the vectors).

Now the subset Ann$(u)=\{p(X)\in \mathbb{F}[X]\;|\;p(u)=0_K\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}[X]$.

Then, $U^{\bot}$ is the subset of all vectors that are perpendicular to every vector in $U$ with respect to an inner product on some inner product space (it is called the orthogonal complement of $U$). It is actually quite easy to see that if $U \subset V$ then we must have $V^{\perp} \subset U^{\perp}$.

So in your question - the text that you are quoting (?) - I think the annihilator is referring to a subset of vectors that are orthogonal to every vector in another subset, it annihilates the second subset in the sense that its inner product with any vector in the second subset is $0$. One illustrative example: Suppose $A$ is some $n \times n$ matrix with real entries, and considering the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the rowspace of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the nullspace of $A$, and rowspace($A)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, but the only vector which is orthogonal to every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the $0$-vector. So $\mathbb{R}^{n \perp} \subseteq$ nullspace$(A)$.

Anyway, so the way to prove that if $U \subset V$ then we must have $V^{\perp} \subset U^{\perp}$, is to just consider any $v \in V^\perp$, and then to show that it must be in $U^\perp$...and then you must show there is some $u \in U^\perp$ that is not in $V^\perp$...it is quite straightforward to do this.

Comment: I know you say its straighforward to do this but I'm still kind of shaky on how to show that.

Comment: I think I gave you enough clues to think and work out the answer for yourself, if you just want to be spoonfed the correct answer each time you will never learn to do maths yourself...